# CSS bug only in firefox div background replaced by part of divs

Tags: html, css, firefox

I worked on some website and I get this in firefox:

http://i.imgur.com/BRIBTwF.png

and in Chrome, Opera and even IE10 I get as it should be:

http://i.imgur.com/75wXr1c.png

This is my css:

```
.carousel-bottom{

background:  -webkit-gradient(radial, rgba(255,255,255,1) 48%,rgba(168,168,183,1) 90%), url('../img/texture.png'); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,1) 48%,rgba(168,168,183,1) 90%), url('../img/texture.png');
background: -moz-radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,1) 48%,rgba(168,168,183,1) 90%), url('../img/texture.png'); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,1) 48%,rgba(168,168,183,1) 90%), url('../img/texture.png'); /* IE10 */
background: -o-radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,1) 48%,rgba(168,168,183,1) 90%), url('../img/texture.png'); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: radial-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,1) 48%,rgba(168,168,183,1) 90%), url('../img/texture.png'); /* W3C */
height:15px;
box-shadow: 1px -1px 2px grey inset;
overflow:none !important;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

Anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: The radial gradient background work slightly different in FF. See the MDN documentation.

Comment: Change gradient to linear if it's not a problem...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient
 Here you can find what you need

Comment: While the link may answer the question, it is always better to include the essential parts here mate. That way your answer will not lose its worth even if the link becomes inactive. I know this is MDN URL and is not likely to become inactive anytime soon, but still.

Comment: Thanks mate, I didn't think about that. I'll keep that in mind in future.